# Xcode 4.4.1 how to refresh a global variable via a label?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a global variable that stores some `Float32` data. 
I have a label and a button in my viewcontroller. I want the label to automatically update the content of the global variable when the button is pressed.
How do I do this?
I have a function associated to the button:

```
- (IBAction)Start:(id)sender {

    // some code

    NSString *dBstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f dB", decibels];

    self.output.text = dBstring;

}
```

But the value does not get updated on the label when running.

I tried to put the code in the `viewDidLoad` function, but it didn't work.

What should I do?

Any information is appreciated.

```
global variable:

extern Float32 decibels;
```

Comment: what's the value of `decibels`?

Comment: Do an `NSLog(@"Decibels: %f", decibels);` to check if there is a value associated with the variable. If there is, make sure your connections are setup properly in XCode.

Comment: The decibels variable updates its value. If I tap the button multiple times the value on the label changes. It just doesn't automatically change.

Comment: Just to clarify, your saying that `decibels` is updated to the correct value when you press the button, but the label does not update to show the new value for `decibels`?

Comment: @forgot， yes decibels updates its value when I press the button, but the label doesn't automatically updates. Any idea why?

Comment: You say that if you tap the button multiple times, it will eventually update? Is there something going on in `// some code` that might be keeping the UI from updating?

Comment: @forgot，if I tap the button multiple times, it updates only after I tap the button. So it does not automatically updates. // some code just starts the audio unit.

Comment: Problem solved. For anyone who has similar problem: Start a NStimer in the viewDidLoad function with selector: updateLabel. Write a updateLabel function to update the decibel value.